# Designing composite rowkey for Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to create a hbase table with following structure.

```
**rowkey**                  |**CF1**
(customerid,txtimestamp)|customerid,amount
```

1. I want to query records using customerid for certain period range.
2. My rowkey uses customer id in reverse order and transaction timestamp.

Long customerid=Long.valueOf(new StringBuilder(customerid).reverse().toString());

byte[] rowKey = Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(customerid),Bytes.toBytes(txtimestamp.getTime()));

1. How do I desige row key so that it gets split into 4 region server?
2. Is there any efficient row key design method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reverse customer_id, it makes no sense

If you want to split all data across 4 regions, you can prefix all keys with values 0-3, for example:

```
int partition = customer_id % 4;
byte[] rowKey = Bytes.add(
                   Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(partition)),
                   Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(customer_id)),
                   Bytes.toBytes(txTimestamp.getTime())
                );
```

In this case you need to create your table with split keys using this HBaseAdmin method

```
public void createTable(final HTableDescriptor desc, byte [][] splitKeys)
```

Split keys would be :

```
byte[][] splitKeys = new byte[3][];
splitKeys[0] = "1".getBytes();
splitKeys[1] = "2".getBytes();
splitKeys[2] = "3".getBytes();
```

so all keys starting with 0 go to first region, keys starting with 1 goes to second region and so on

Comment: Can we specify split in hbase shell? Also, what if we use ascii instead of bytes for splitkeys?

Comment: @kinkajou for 1 question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863285

Comment: @kinkajou hbase key comparator compares raw bytes, keep that in mind when choosing partitioning

Comment: I get partition over 3 server now. Actually I am getting 1st server 0, 2nd Server 1, 2nd Server 2, 3rd Server 3, 4th Server unused. Is this some science?

Comment: @kinkajou i see. you got 4 regions as expected, but hbase decided to put two of them on the same server. there is a method to manually assign a region to server. Here's a snippet https://gist.github.com/sergey-sw/4ced9399b6df711c0cbfb35b0f69763f